# Creating a XML file with DTD need some help on the coding format

Tags: xml, dtd

New to XML and DTD, I'm trying to parse this XML file to DTD, not sure if i'm doing it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Heres a sample of my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<!ELEMENT ConutryList (CountryReccord) +>
<!ATTLIST CountryList
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ' '>

<!ELEMENT CountryRecord (name,alpha-2,alpha-3,country-code,iso_3166-2,region,sub-region,intermediate-region,region-code,sub-region-code,
intermediate-region-code,capital-city,currency,currency-code, population)>

<!ATTLIST CountryRecord
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ' '>

... more DTD codes but limited space
```

The above is DTD, below is the XML.

```
<CountryList>
  <CountryRecord>
  <name> Afganistan </name>
  <alpha-2> AF </alpha-2>
  <country-code> AFG </country-code>
  <iso_3166-2> </iso_3166-2>
  <region> </region>
  <sub-region>   </sub-region>
  <intermediate-region> </intermediate-region>
  <region-code>  </region-code>
  <sub-region-code>  </sub-region-code>
  <intermediate-region-code>  </intermediate-region-code>
  <capital-city> </capital-city>
  <currency>  </currency>
  <currency-code>  </currency-code>
  <population>  </population>
  </CountryRecord>
</CountryList>
```

Comment: Another question is that what if there is no information provided for certain country records like<intermediate-region> <intermediate-region-code> is not provided. Do I leave it empty or I should uhhh delete the attributes?

Comment: This is slightly different from https://stackoverflow.com/q/58778151/407651, but similar enough to be closed as duplicate IMHO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this DTD declaration correctly phrased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778151/is-this-dtd-declaration-correctly-phrased)

Comment: Yes, that thread is also posted by me, can i ask if there is no data from lets say sub-region-code, do I just leave it blank or not?